# Why does bazel not include the exit code in the BEP for failed spawn actions?

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to work on my tooling around bazel, and trying to investigate the BEP.

When looking at a failed action it seems that while there is a field for the exit code and it is included in the text in the standard bazel output it isn't in the BuildEvent proto.

Example line from bazel:

> ERROR: /Users/endobson/proj/racket/yaspl2/libraries/BUILD:703:1: Couldn't build file libraries/resolved-imports-language-test_lib.o: YasplCompile libraries/resolved-imports-language-test_lib.o failed (Exit 1) library_compiler failed: error executing command prebuilt/saved/library_compiler osx bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/resolved-imports-language-test_lib.o bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/resolved-imports-language-test_lib.sig ... (remaining 14 argument(s) skipped)

Example output in the BEP:

```
event {
id {
  action_completed {
    primary_output: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/resolved-imports-language-test_lib.o"
    label: "//libraries:resolved-imports-language-test_lib"
    configuration {
      id: "a0d10a93870b235ffa7696ba8caa20c0"
    }
  }
}
action {
  stderr {
    name: "stderr"
    uri: "http://localhost:9100/cas/e19f91034d4477810ba05603b847e8072a8a1c0787da159ad535344693fb9995"
  }
  label: "//libraries:resolved-imports-language-test_lib"
  configuration {
    id: "a0d10a93870b235ffa7696ba8caa20c0"
  }
  type: "YasplCompile"
  command_line: "prebuilt/saved/library_compiler"
  command_line: "osx"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/resolved-imports-language-test_lib.o"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/resolved-imports-language-test_lib.sig"
  command_line: "libraries/resolved-imports-language-test.yaspl"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/module-name.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/module-signature.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/resolved-imports-language.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/source-language.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/top-level-name.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/variant-info.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/yunit.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/data/bytes.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/data/dict.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/data/either.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/data/indexed-set.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/data/list.sig"
  command_line: "bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/libraries/data/maybe.sig"
}
}
```

Field definition: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/4ba404f7ed0473df3f0effa016c107ef677464f6/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventstream/proto/build_event_stream.proto#L448

It looks like the code is dropped here:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/08d691f40bbe8c6ed28a5ba22798f0cbee595fa7/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/exec/SpawnExecException.java#L83

This might be because this code is conflating the exit code of the subprocess with a possible exit code of bazel, as that is what the ExitCode class seems to be.